# PHP text as hyperlink in echo

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am pretty sure this will be an easy task to do for some PHP programmers I just can't figure it out how to do it. I am displaying some info from my database but want to be able to display it as Hyperlink text instead of the whole website so when someone click on "Website" it will take them to the url. Here is my code:

```
 <li style="margin-left: 50px;font-family: Myriad Pro Bold ! important;"><b style="margin-right: 20px;">Website:</b> <?php echo $row->website; ?></li></li>
```

I am looking forward to add 2 texts to the code for example:

```
 <li style="margin-left: 50px;font-family: Myriad Pro Bold ! important;"><b style="margin-right: 20px;">Website:</b> <?php [SHOW: (**Website** as a hyperlink text) (**Blog** as a Hyper link text) echo $row->website; ?></li></li>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: What does `$row->website` contain?

Comment: Pulls Website URL from phpmyadmin database Eggyal

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="<?php echo $row->website; ?>"><?php echo $row->blog; ?></a>
```

Just guessing that `$row` has a member called `blog` as well that has the title, and that `$row->website` is the full url (`http://bleh`)

Comment: Assuming short tags are "ON"

Comment: I don't judge/estimate people's (PHP) skills, however many do not even know what the term means lol. +1 for added explanation ;-)

Comment: You shouldn't use the shorthand as it's OFF by default in 5.3 and newer, I believe.

Comment: @ahwm Paul added an explanation along with the added `<?php`

Comment: I didn't know that.  Updating.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know that. I just thought it prudent to add that in newer versions it's off by default.

Comment: Thank you Paul!!!! Final code is here: `<li style="margin-left: 50px;font-family: Myriad Pro Bold ! important;"><b style="margin-right: 20px;">Website:</b> <a href="<?php echo $row->website; ?>">Website</a></li></li>` :)

Comment: Apparently I was partly wrong, anyway. According to the PHP Manual, `short_open_tag` option no longer affects `<?=` `?>` since 5.4.0. It was probably just 5.3 that turned it off by default which also affected the shorthand echo. There are some standards which recommend only using `<?php` `?>`, though.

Comment: Thank you ahwm. Don't beat yourself about this. I have plenty of code to share..stay tuned lol

Comment: @ahwm: Serves you right for not using smarty or some other template engine. :)

Comment: Well let's wrap this one up by accepting the answer as correct @JohnLee - seems like this one's got a **"Happy Ending"** after all. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the href is already within a string, you have two options:

**Single/Double quotes**

```
$string = '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>';
```

**Escaping**

```
$string = "<a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a>";
```

Otherwise, you can insert PHP into your link, like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo $row->link; ?>">Google</a>
```

If this is not what you are looking for, I am sorry I misunderstood the question.

Edit:

I suggest you use CSS rather than inline styles, would simplify your code and look less sloppy.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! This ius exactly what I was looking for. I also do what I can, I am in the learning process but I agree with you about the CSS. Final Code: `<li style="margin-left: 50px;font-family: Myriad Pro Bold ! important;"><b style="margin-right: 20px;">Website:</b> <a href="<?php echo $row->website; ?>">Website</a></li></li>`

Comment: If this is the result you were looking for, I suggest you mark this post as the correct solution so other people can see easily what worked for them, saving them time on their research. I personally don't try anything on a post that hasn't been marked as solved since I do not know if their was a proper solution to the problem at hand.